# Rails3 Active Admin: How to display only Open status records when first click on Shipments tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin. I have a list of Shipments with status (as a string) of Open and Closed. When the user clicks on the Shipments tab, I want to display only the Open shipments. How can I do that? Of course, the user could later choose to see the Closed shipments by using the filter. But I want the default to initially only show the Open shipments.

Answer (score 2):

Probably best way will be to create scopes in model. AA automatically gets your scopes and creates tabs above table in index view. Remember to add scopes in app/admin/your-resource-name.rb file.

```
#app/models/shipments.rb
  scope :opened, where(:status => "Open")
  scope :closed, where(:status => "Closed")
```

... and add scopes to resource file

```
#app/admin/shipments.rb
  scope :opened
  scope :closed
```

I don't have time to test, but it should work.

ASCIIcast with simple scope: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit please?

Comment: yes, that looks good, but im looking for the default to only display Open shipments. when you first click on the Shipments tab, to ONLY show open shipments.

Answer (score 2):

scopes in the model:

```
#app/models/shipments.rb
  scope :opened, where(:status => "Open")
  scope :closed, where(:status => "Closed")
```

scopes in the activeadmin resource, one marked as default:

```
#app/admin/shipments.rb
  scope :opened, :default => :true
  scope :closed
```