# Rails Active Admin Scope with Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Using active admin with ActiveRecord scopes was explained here: [Rails3 Active Admin: How to display only Open status records when first click on Shipments tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486771/rails3-active-admin-how-to-display-only-open-status-records-when-first-click-on)

Now I'm trying to do it for a scope **with params**.

In my model i have:

```
#app/models/shipments.rb
scope :by_status, -> (status) { where(status: status) }
```

I want to be able to use this in `app/admin/shipments.rb` to be something like

```
# app/admin/shipments.rb
scope :by_status 'open'
```

Is there an active admin way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a block:

```
  scope :open do |shipments|
    shipments.by_status('open')
  end
```

If you want this to be the default scope:

```
  scope :open, default: true do |shipments|
    shipments.by_status('open')
  end
```